# Unity - multiple enemies using RaycastHit incorrectly

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

So, I have a script attached to the enemy prefab. Each time the enemy casts a ray to the player's collider, an Activity X happens. Everything works fine with a single enemy but when there is more than one, the Activity X starts working incorrectly.
The code is the following:

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out enemyHit))
    {
        if (enemyHit.collider.gameObject.tag == "PlayerCollider" && aI_Movement.isFiring == true)
        {
            activityX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            activityX = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that the problem happens because of the contradicting information from the RaycastHit (say, one enemy does hit the target collider and the other does not, so the prerequisites for the Activity X are both true and false at the same time). I tried playing with the conditions of the children's "if" clauses and did a lot of other tweaks but nothing helped so far.

Is there any way to make it work correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Is `activityX` a `static`? If so why?!

Comment: Nope, it is not static but thanks for the plausible assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the if/else after the Raycast, I would use a layermask to check if the player is hit by a Raycast. And then call the action.

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out enemyHit, playerLayer)
{
    activityX = false;
}
```

However, even if you put an else statement after this, then, again, you would have the same problem as before, with one enemy starting the activity, and another stopping it.

A work around for this, is instead of calling an activity, set a `bool` to `true`. And only allow the player object to set it `false`.

Not sure on what type of game you are building, but let's say that when the player gets hit by the raycast, he starts acting scared and running in circles.

As it is, he gets hit by one raycast, starts running, and immediately stops, because 5 other enemy raycasts have shot out and missed him.

With the raycast only setting true if hitting, he would get hit, and continuing running in circles even if 100 more raycasts missed. Then you would have some kind of timer, or check on the player object to set the `bool` to `false`.

**To make it simple. Use the raycast to start the action, but not to stop the action. That should be done elsewhere.**